# Flutter sort List of Objects after two values

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart, array-multisort

I have a `List` of `CustomObjects` that I need to sort. First the objects should be sorted after their property `dateTime` and if that is the same, it should be sorted after another property, the `compare`-property.

I searched for multisort and found this:

```
medcimentNotificationListData.sort((med1, med2) {
  var r = med1.datetime.compareTo(med2.datetime);
  if (r != 0) return r;
  return med1.mealTimeDescription.compareValue
      .compareTo(med2.mealTimeDescription.compareValue);
});
```

But when printing the list  right after it, the list is not sorted..

```
medcimentNotificationListData.forEach((medicamentNotificationData) {
  print(
      '${medicamentNotificationData.title}, order: ${medicamentNotificationData.mealTimeDescription.compareValue}');
});
```

What am I missing here? Is there an *easy*  way to multisort?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: you are doing it right. are there any errors

Comment: @sajithlakmal there are no errors. Could you explain what this is actually doing? what is `r` and why the comparison `r != 0`?

Comment: It is an `int`  which can be either -1, 0, or 1 . if it is -1 it mean the `a` element is will be placed before the `b` element of the list. 0 means the elements ` a` and `b` are equal, 1 means element `a`  is after the element `b` in the order.

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling the `sort()` method the function calls `(a, b) { // your function}` which should return either -1 , 0 or 1 . this function is called on the existing order.
at first your element `a` is your first element and element `b` is second element of the list as the existing order of the list

if your function returns -1 it means your element `a` should be placed before the element `b` therefore it places `a` before the `b` and call the function again by replacing older element `b` as new element `a` and new element `b` will be the element after the old `b` element.

if your function returns 0 it means elements `a` and `b` are both same. therefore it places `a` before the `b` and call the function again by replacing older element `b` as new element `a`.

but when your function returns the 1 it means your element `a` is coming after the element `b`. therefore the function is called again by replacing element `a` with the element before the old element `a`.

**Following code shows how this is works**

```
final List<int> list = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2 , 6, 8, 2 , 5];
 list.sort((a,b)  {
        print("a : $a, b : $b");
        int result = a.compareTo(b);
        print('result : $result \n');
        return result;
      });
```

**output**

```
a : 1, b : 0
result : 1

a : 1, b : 3
result : -1

a : 3, b : 4
result : -1

a : 4, b : 2
result : 1

a : 3, b : 2
result : 1

a : 1, b : 2
result : -1

a : 4, b : 6
result : -1

a : 6, b : 8
result : -1

a : 8, b : 2
result : 1

a : 6, b : 2
result : 1

a : 4, b : 2
result : 1

a : 3, b : 2
result : 1

a : 2, b : 2
result : 0

a : 8, b : 5
result : 1

a : 6, b : 5
result : 1

a : 4, b : 5
result : -1
```